# Laravel 7 route issue

Tags: laravel

I have this in web.php:

```
Route::get('courseDash', 'CoursesController@dashboard')->name('courses');
```

And when I access the welcome page, which contains:

```
href={{ route('courseDash') }}"
```

It says Route [courseDash] not defined.
But I can access the target page using url() or localhost/courseDash. Why is that?

Comment: you have defined a `named` route for your routes. Try `{{route('courses')}}` instead.

Comment: Thanks Sid. I thought the name should be registered somewhere else. I finally get the idea here.